# Spring WebClient multiple retryWhen to handle different errors

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webclient, spring-reactive

Could I be able to add multiple `retryWhen` to perform retries to handle **different WebClient failure responses**?

**What I want to achieve:**

I am using WebClient to make REST API Calls. There are few error scenarios, when happens I need to perform retry, but with different delays.

For eg, 
 1. if `401 Unauthorize` happens, I can retry immediately after refreshing the token. 
 2. If `502/503 Server` error happens, I need to delay the retries after 5 sec. 
 3. if `429 Too Many Request` happens, I need to delay the retry little longer, say 20sec after.

I would like to create Retry spec like below:

```
    protected static final Predicate<Throwable> is401 =
                (throwable) -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException.Unauthorized;

        protected static final Predicate<Throwable> is5xx =
                (throwable) -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException.ServiceUnavailable;

        protected static final Predicate<Throwable> is429 =
                (throwable) -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException.TooManyRequests;

        Retry retry401 = Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                    .filter(is401)
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> retrySignal.failure());

        Retry retry5xx = Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                    .filter(is5xx)
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> retrySignal.failure());

        Retry retry429 = Retry.fixedDelay(5, Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                    .filter(is429)
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> retrySignal.failure());

// trying to apply the to WebClient like below:
    WebClient.Builder()
        .get()
        .uri("endpointuri")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(String.class)
        .retryWhen(retry401)
        .retryWhen(retry5xx)
        .retryWhen(retry429);
```

Looks like `.retryWhen(retry429)' overwrites the other retries.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen if you get 401,500,401,429? Should it reset? Should it keep count per error?

Answer (score 4):

> Looks like `.retryWhen(retry429)' overwrites the other retries.

This is false. `retryWhen` is a composite operator that builds upon the existing publisher - you can chain it as many times as you like. The only time you need to worry about one retry "overriding" another is when your `filter` predicates overlap.

Even in this case, it looks like it's "first wins" (in the chain) not "last wins".

Your problems instead may be to do with this line:

```
protected static final Predicate<Throwable> is5xx =
            (throwable) -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException.ServiceUnavailable;
```

From your naming and your description, it looks like you want this to catch any 5xx error - but it'll only catch 503 (which is specifically assigned to "service unavailable".)

If you're trying with something different, like a 502 or 500 error - then none of the predicates (and therefore retries) you've defined will match.

Instead, to check for any 5xx error, you likely want:

```
protected static final Predicate<Throwable> is5xx =
        (throwable) -> throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException && ((WebClientResponseException)throwable).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError();
```